# Display the third post in different style WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have five post (or more) to display, but I want to display two posts in two columns and then the next post in one column. I'm trying with the code (wp) below but this does not work.

My HTML:

```
<div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5"></div>
<div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5"></div>
<div class="inner w-full col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  pl-5 pr-5"></div>
<div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5"></div>
<div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5"></div>
<div class="inner w-full col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  pl-5 pr-5"></div>
```

My WordPress code:

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'history', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
$post_count = 0;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if($post_count <= 2) {
    ?>
       <div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5">

       </div>
     <?php } else ?>
       <div class="inner w-full col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  pl-5 pr-5">

       </div>
       <?php $post_count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
       <?php else : ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'testpost', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
                    $post_count = 1;
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                        if($post_count % 3 != 0) {
                        ?>
                            <div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5">

                            </div>
                            <?php } else{ ?>
                            <div class="inner w-full col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  pl-5 pr-5">

                            </div>

                        <?php  } $post_count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking post count is less than or equal to 2, so it will truncate at 3, you can use multiples of 3 as below

You can try this

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'history', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
$post_count = 0;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if($post_count % 3 != 0) {
    ?>
        <div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-5 pr-5">

        </div>
        <?php } else ?>
        <div class="inner w-full col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  pl-5 pr-5">

        </div>

    <?php $post_count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this code will result to have each div structure one by one it will not work like two time first one and one time second one